# How to perform null check in java 8

Tags: java, foreach, java-stream

How to write below code in java 8

```
List<String> names = service.serviceCall();

if(names != null) { // **how to do this null check with java 8**
    names.forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

Comment: https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/java8-optional.html

Comment: `if(names != null) { … }` is exactly how we do this in Java 8. Unless we manage to convince the author of `serviceCall()` to stop returning `null` for a collection type…

Comment: The `if` statement has not been deprecated.

Comment: This is correct but try to avoid passing in nulls as checks. Use the answer provided below. Optional is a nice feature of java 8 which I prefer to the above

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can do:

```
Optional.ofNullable(names).orElse(Collections.emptyList()).forEach(System.out::println);
```

or

```
Optional.ofNullable(names).ifPresent(n -> n.forEach(System.out::println));
```

or

```
Stream.of(names)
    .filter(Objects::nonNull)
    .flatMap(Collection::stream)
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

but don't. Look at all all that extra stuff you'd have to write.

Just use a plain old null check, like you have in your code already.

Answer (score 2):

As the [Answer by Andy Turner](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60642607/642706) suggest, writing a plain null check is best here.

## `Objects.nonNull`

But Java 8 does offer one minor improvement: methods on the `Objects` utility class for the null check.

- [`Objects.isNull`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Objects.html#isNull(java.lang.Object))
- [`Objects.nonNull`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Objects.html#nonNull(java.lang.Object))

So your code would like this.

```
List<String> names = service.serviceCall();

if( Objects.nonNull( names ) ) 
{   
    names.forEach( System.out::println );
}
```

## `Objects.requireNonNullElseGet`

Another method on `Objects` can return an alternate object if that suits your situation. For example, if your service call returns null list, perhaps you should substitute an empty list. Call [`Objects.requireNonNullElseGet`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Objects.html#requireNonNullElseGet(T,java.util.function.Supplier)).

The lambda passed is handled in a lazy manner, not executed unless needed.

```
List<String> names = 
        Objects.requireNonNullElseGet
        ( 
            service.serviceCall() , 
            () -> new ArrayList<>( 0 )  // In Java 9 and later, use `List.of()`.
        )
;
names.forEach( System.out::println );
```

Comment: "But Java 8 does offer one minor improvement: methods on the Objects utility class for the null check." These methods are not intended to replace null checks. They exist simply to give you a method reference to use inside a method chain, e.g. `filter(Objects::nonNull)`. Where possible, a plain old null check is preferable.

Comment: @AndyTurner Why can’t the `Objects` methods be used in other contexts? Calls like `Objects.nonNull` are easier to read and less error-prone than the older syntax of `!= null`. As seen in my last example, using `Objects.requireNonNull` to provide an alternate object in the case of receiving a null is compact and self-documenting. Your comment leaves me puzzled.

Comment: perhaps you like Yoda conditions; I think "objects non null thing" reads far less naturally than "thing is not null". To each his own. But I am referring to the Javadoc which explicitly calls out the intended usage; one must question why the API designers went to the additional effort of saying that. I don't really feel it's any less error-prone either: I sometimes invert a condition by mistake, but I don't think that's got anything to do with `==` vs `!=` over `isNull` vs `nonNull`. Plus, you have the additional error possibility of an unintentionally primitive argument.

Comment: @AndyTurner Regarding "the Javadoc which explicitly calls out the intended usage", I do not find this in [the Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Objects.html). Please cite.

Comment: it's an `@apiNote` on the methods, in the page you link: "This method exists to be used as a Predicate, filter(Objects::isNull)", "This method exists to be used as a Predicate, filter(Objects::nonNull)".